# SpriteKit categoryBitMask issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Spritekit, and I'm having some trouble with something simple.

I'm making a pinball game. In order to detect collisions and award points with the ball, the bumpers have the following set:

```
categoryBitMask

collisionBitMask

contactTestBitMask
```

However, once I set categoryBitMask, the object no longer acts the same way. The ball passes through the bumper.

I've tried to set the properties in code to mirror what is set in the SKS file:

```
    physicsBody?.isDynamic
    physicsBody?.affectedByGravity 
    physicsBody?.allowsRotation
    physicsBody?.pinned
    physicsBody?.mass
```

But this doesn't make any difference.

How can I make a SKSpriteNode maintain it's physical properties after setting the categoryBitMask?

Comment: Share your exact values of `categoryBitMask`, `collisionBitMask`, `contactTestBitMask`  both for pinball `physicsBody` & bumper `phycicsBody`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was setting the collision on one object but not the other

ball.collisionBitMask = ...contains bumper
ball.contactTestBitMask = ... contains bumper

but not the bumper:
bumper.collisionBitMask = ...didn't contain ball
bumper.contactTestBitMask = ...didn't contain ball